# insert \n in every space for multiple strings python

Tags: python, string

I have a list of strings:

```
['Hello Yes', 'Good Now Order', 'Been There Before', 'Because']
```

I want to rewrite this as:

```
['Hello\nYes', 'Good\nNow\nOrder', 'Been\nThere\nBefore', 'Because']
```

So the `\n` goes into every space except the beginning or end of the string.

I have tried `.split(' ')` inside a for loop, but that gets messy and then unsure how to rejoin at the end.

Comment: Hint: Look at `str.replace`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following comprehension that uses the split and join approach you are suggesting:

```
l = ['Hello Yes', 'Good Now Order', 'Been There Before', 'Because']
l_new = ['\n'.join(s.split()) for s in l]  
# this would replace any sequence of whitespace by a single line break
```

or perhaps more readable and to the point, using `str.replace`:

```
l_new = [s.replace(' ', '\n') for s in l]
# this will replace all and only space characters
```

Comment: Shorter? :P 33 chars in each

Comment: @HFBrowning Shorter in the sense of fewer function calls ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try a list comprehension (this returns a new list with every element the same as in the old one, but with spaces replaced with linebreaks):

```
[element.replace(' ', '\n') for element in ls]
```

where `ls` is your list.

Alternatively, you could do a for-loop, using the `replace` method.

Comment: Ah schwobaseggl beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ['Hello Yes', 'Good Now Order', 'Been There Before', 'Because']
list(map('\n'.join, map(str.split, l)))
# ['Hello\nYes', 'Good\nNow\nOrder', 'Been\nThere\nBefore', 'Because']
```

Comment: The quality of this answer will be greatly increased if you explain your code, especially for new users learning this.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.